# Cross Validation in Classification

Tags: image-processing, classification, cross-validation

I have two different datasets, datset X and dataset Y... From which I calculate features to use for classification..

Case 1. When I  combine both together as one large datset then use 10 fold cross validation I get very good classification results with accuracy and AUC > 95%

Case2. Yet if I use one of the datasets for training and the other for testing, results fall severely low with both accuracy and AUC becoming ~ 50%

My questions are:

1. Which of the cases' results is more reliable??
2. And why the huge difference in results??

Thanks..

Comment: did I answer your question? Do you need any extra help?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a bias in the way the datasets were obtained that makes you get worst results.

Read [this](http://blog.smola.org/post/4110255196/real-simple-covariate-shift-correction).

Another thing is that on one case you are training your classifier with a smaller dataset (the two combined is larger assuming they are about the same size, even with the 10 fold cross validation). This **necessarily** causes a poorer performance.

So my answers would be:

1. Depends on how you obtained both datasets and on how the final classifier will be used.
2. Differences in the **size of the training set** and **bias** on how they are obtained.